# Kenesis keyboard: mac command key stopped working

Tags: kinesis-advantage

Suddenly my mac command (aka clover key) stopped working. I tried remapping other thumb buttons to it, but it either acts like an option or a control key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit the `=` and `m` keys at the same time to get back into mac mode. If your function keys all of a sudden start to act like media keys, this can also fix that problem.

Comment: For reference in the future: http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/support/technical-support/troubleshoooting-advantage/ under "Ctrl, Alt/Option, and/or Windows/Command keys are not working correctly"

Comment: Ugh... This isn't working for me. I reset my keys, and now it's stuck in PC mode with just alt and control available. I do have a PS2 cable (Swapped the USB cable with PS2) instead of USB, so I wonder if that's causing issues. Would hate to need to re-open this thing to change the cable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a newer Kinesis Advantage, the suggestion to press `=m` might not work. It didn't work on mine.

If your keyboard has labels on the F5/F6/F7 keys that read "mac", "pc", and "win", try this instead: Hold 'progm' (the top-rightmost key) and press F5 to enable Mac keyboard map.